# This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is as weird as it gets.

I've been using the same paypal code on my dev enviroment (sandbox) for over 2 months.

Today when I get redirected to paypal (to pay a transaction) I get this error

[image]

I have no clue about what could possibly be cuasing this error as I didn't change ANYTHING in the code at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was an paypal intermitent problem, 
trying a few hours later did the trick.
Weird...